# Internal mail system

Tags: 7, emails

How do I allow users send emails to the other users?
What module can I use to allow users to email each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about 'best' (although @Berdir might have something to say on the matter ;) ), but [Privatemsg](http://drupal.org/project/privatemsg) would probably be perfect for this:

> Privatemsg allows your site's visitors to send private messages to each other.

It also provides e-mail notifications of new messages.

Comment: I don't know of a better alternative in Drupal, but I wouldn't say Privatemsg is the "best", that's quite a big word. There are many things that could be better :)

Comment: I used private messages on a dating site, works flawlessly, what other options exist?